# Неадекватное поведение Visual Studio при добавлении классов в проект с указанием каталога создания файлов

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Скажите, пожалуйста, существует ли способ решить следующую проблему в `Visual Studio`:

1. Есть проект, в котором весьма глубокая структура каталогов.
2. Выполняется добавление в проект нового класса в один из каталогов (`hpp` + `cpp` файлы).
3. В диалоговом окне указывается имя класса и путь к каталогу.
   [image]
4. Далее появляется другое диалоговое окно, в котором можно поменять имя класса и имена `hpp` и `cpp` файлов. Для файлов также можно выбрать каталог (еще раз...). Если я нажимаю на кнопку с многоточием для указания каталога `hpp` или `cpp` файлу, то вижу совершенно не тот путь, который указывался на шаге `3`. Допустим, для файлов вновь задается верный каталог. Нажимается `OK`.
   [image]
5. Класс в проект добавляется, соответствующие ему файлы создаются и с очень высокой вероятностью появляются в каком угодно каталоге, но только не в том, который задавался целых три раза.

Как с этим бороться? Такое поведение наблюдается уже давно (годы), и порядком мешает работе

Comment: Из всего вышеперечисленного воспроизводится только №3 - Location указанный действительно игнорируется. Пишите в саппорт. Хотя мне на практике этот диалог создания класса представляется совершенно бесполезным. Никогда им не пользуюсь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Система проектов С++ в Visual Studio вообще толком не поддерживает вложенные каталоги (в отличие от C#, например). Для организации проекта используются фильтры по расширениям, в которых в кучу показываются файлы из разных физических каталогов. Диалог создания класса тут только часть проблемы. Насчет этого уже открывали баг: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/8138/c-project-context-menu-add-class-adds-the-class-to.html, но он был закрыт как "by design".

Но в качестве обходного пути можно сделать так:

1. Включить в обозревателе решений "Показать все файлы":

[image: solution explorer]

При этом вместо фильтров отобразиться физическая структура каталогов. Увы, вместе с ней отобразиться в всякий мусор, вроде Debug/Release :(

2. Добавляем класс как обычно, в корневой каталог проекта.
3. В обозревателе решений берем полученные файлы Class.cpp и Class.hpp и перетаскиваем в нужный вложенный каталог.

Тогда файлы будут физически перемещены в нужный вложенный каталог.